# NiFi unable to open couchbase bucket

Tags: apache-nifi, couchbase

I have a flow set up in NiFi to pull topics off a message bus and write them to a Couchbase bucket.  The issue I am experiencing is when I start the flow, the messages are pulled off the bus and queued in NiFi, but when the NiFi Couchbase processor tries to write to the bucket I get an error stating the the bucket could not be opened.  Ive verified couchbase user and bucket name match on the NiFi putcouchbasekey.

```
5:51:32 UTC ERROR
PutCouchbaseKey[id=08732975-0177-1000-4bbe-773a970bf14a] Failed to process session due to Writing document 421af279-017c-4b96-9b84-dc1cf1436db9 to Couchbase Server using StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=421af279-017c-4b96-9b84-dc1cf1436db9,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1610754666781-177, container=default, section=177], offset=980537, length=31575],offset=0,name=421af279-017c-4b96-9b84-dc1cf1436db9,size=31575] failed due to com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: Could not open bucket.: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Writing document 421af279-017c-4b96-9b84-dc1cf1436db9 to Couchbase Server using StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=421af279-017c-4b96-9b84-dc1cf1436db9,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1610754666781-177, container=default, section=177], offset=980537, length=31575],offset=0,name=421af279-017c-4b96-9b84-dc1cf1436db9,size=31575] failed due to com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: Could not open bucket.
```

Comment: what version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: @Matthew Groves. Enterprise 6.6.1. Figured it out though, when Couchbase uses routable DNS names rather than the IPs to identify the nodes, NiFi would could not reach the bucket.  When we switched to the IPs it worked.

Comment: Glad you figured it out; I love hearing about NiFi in action, I think it's a great, underrated tool :)

Answer (score 1):

When Couchbase uses routable DNS names rather than the IPs to identify the nodes, NiFi would could not reach the bucket.  When we switched to the IPs it worked.

Answer (score 0):

following up Matthew Groves response, The `org.apache.nifi-nifi-couchbase-nar` is package with older version of couchbase client library. if your server is 6.X and above it, won't work.